# Is there any way to connect MongoDb server to power Bi cloud?

Tags: mongodb, powerbi, odbc, powerbi-desktop

I need a work around how to connect MongoDB ( running on a server ) with powerBI server directly without powerBI desktop intervention.

Previously, I did it like connect mongodb ( local ) with powerBI desktop via ODBC, then publish to powerBI server. But once the mongoDb server is in another server then I don't have any idea how to do it.

Can anyone give me any idea/solution, please?

Comment: Usually it should not matter whether your MongoDB runs on local machine or on a remote server. What is your problem? "I got stuck" is not a useful error message. How does your configuration look like?

Comment: You can't use the service to connect to mongodb directly, you need the desktop version to start that process. What is the issue once it is in the service? do you need a gateway to link the service to the local db??

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I think it matters if it is on remote server. Because Once I configure mongoDB Ip address in ODBC, it don't allow me to connect without VPN. Sorry For the words, I edited the post. Thanks

Comment: @Jon once I tried to connect with the mongoDB server I've two issue one: once I configure mongoDB Ip address in ODBC driver, it don't allow me to connect without VPN  two: I need to get to get rid of powerBI desktop intervention.  I think to connect local DB with powerBI, I don't need gateway. I did it using publish option to powerBI workspace. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mongo is an ODBC data source for Power BI, and all [ODBC data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources) require a [Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) to refresh from the Power BI Service.